# WebService How do i pass parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the following webservice function call I found on another question here but I am confused as how to pass parameters its says to pass it as json but normally a php service paramerter is just a /pm1/pm2 attached to the end of url  would this function not then work with that approach ?.

Its the bodyParam  string i trying to get working with a Php webserivce.

```
/// <summary>
/// Utility function to get/post WCFRESTService
/// </summary>
/// <param name="methodRequestType">RequestType:GET/POST</param>
/// <param name="methodName">WCFREST Method Name To GET/POST</param>
 /// <param name="bodyParam">Parameter of POST Method (Need serialize to JSON before passed in)</param>

private async Task<string> WCFRESTServiceCall(string methodRequestType, string methodName, string bodyParam = "")

        {
            try {
                string ServiceURI = "hidding for security /index.php/webservice/" + methodName;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(methodRequestType == "GET" ? HttpMethod.Get : HttpMethod.Post, ServiceURI);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyParam))
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(bodyParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                string jsongString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return jsongString;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                return "";            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**
This is how I call the service so how would i Pass in the city here for example

```
    public async Task<MovieDetail> GetMovieShowtimesAsync()
    {
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
        var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieDetail>(jsonresult);


        return jarray;
    }
```

Comment: `/pm1/pm2` at the end of the url sounds like it's part of the path, not a query string, which would look like `?pm1=val1&pm2=val2` at the end of the url.  If the web service requires a POST, then you can't use a query string -- you have to put the params/data in the body.

Comment: @1.618 have a look at the call to the service see if you can explain in full answer i will mark yours as correct answer

Comment: It would help if you could provide more detail about the webservice you're connecting to.

Comment: @1.618 i got it sorted you where correct about the parmeters just had to be passed onto the query i downloaded the source form the site and inspected it